# Apple Push Notification - Can read all incoming messages like Pebble App?

Tags: ios7, sms, apple-push-notifications

Pebble App can read all incoming messages. I want make app that read all messages in push notification center without jailbreak. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No** , It is Not Possible.

You can not read all Notifications.

Comment: They may be use some webservice of something intermediate for that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's a bit too late, but actually it's possible and Apple didn't help Pebble. The trick is "Message Access Protocol" [supported by iPhone 4+](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht3647)

This is the technology used by in-car system, pebble and, recently, [Notifyr](http://www.getnotifyr.com/).