# Catch all iOS push notifications like Pebble is doing

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, raspberry-pi, push

Is there a way to ask the user and give access to the iOS notifications, so that the app can read/forward all iOS Push notifications, like Pebble is doing? It's not a security issue because I want to ask the user if I can...

In my case I want to forward the push notifications to a web server. 
There is only one post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21038171/apple-push-notification-can-read-all-incoming-messages-like-pebble-app) but it's about Bluetooth, and I don't find enough documentations..

The idea:

Send all my notifications to a webserver so that my Raspberry Pi can show them, on a LCD screen or just with a LED.

Answer (score 2):

No, Apple would not allow this for an app, because of privacy.

You would need to connect your raspberry to your iPhone over bluetooth, then you could work something out, like Pebble.

Another way is to jailbreak your iPhone, and then figure out how to get access to notifications.